# Insert black theme to highchart.js?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

The problem I am encountering is that I am trying to turn the white diagram into black diagram by copying the whole code that is already made from **View Visual Theme** and insert it between here... But this is not smart, because I will make more diagrams and I can not copy the whole black theme code into every diagram. I want to put the whole code into a file, and just include in every table I want to have black theme..

```
$(function () {

// Include black theme here, how?  
   ?????

// Diagram code goes here.... 

}
```

[Click on the middle bottom to check the black theme](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update/dark-unica)

Comment: Try the documentation - http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes

Comment: Place the customized theme's code in a separate file and call the file as external script in your code.